# how to identify which cluster belongs to which emotion

Tags: weka

I am new to weka. I need to identify the set of emotions from the blog documents based on Weka tool clustering method. For the emotion detection, I am using different feature sets values (My features are represented as attributes). For example, my data set will be as:

```
@relation emotion

@attribute pos real ->total no of times each part-of-speech(noun,verb,adjective,adverb) occur in the document / Total no of words in the document
@attribute Positive_Words real ->Count of positive words occur in the document / Total no of words in the document
@attribute Negative_Words real ->Count of Negative words occur in the document / Total no of words in the document
@attribute Emotion_Words real ->Count of Emotion words occur in the document / Total no of words in the document
@attribute First_Sent_Weight real ->Weight given to first sentence in each blog / Total no of sentences in the document

@data
0.4, 0.24, 0.43, 0.32, 0.65
0.32, 0.5, 0.74, 0.8, 0.43
```

I have 5000 instances (By giving, each feature set for every 5000 blog documents, I created 5000 instances). These instances are passed into clustering algorithm of K-means in Weka tool and 6 clusters are generated. My doubt is how to identify which cluster belongs to which emotion. Please suggest any ideas. Thanks in advance.